# Parsing Error on if $event->type stripe webhook

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using the following code for a stripe webhook to send cutsom emails to users from phpmailer. It is from [**this gist**](https://gist.github.com/boucher/1708172).

I can't seem to figure out why I get this error, I rarely use php so I am sure it's something I am not familiar with, this is the error I recieve.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$event' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' in /usr/share/nginx/html/emailReceipt.php on line 24

Code

```
<?php

// SETUP:
// 1. Customize all the settings (stripe api key, email settings, email text)
// 2. Put this code somewhere where it's accessible by a URL on your server.
// 3. Add the URL of that location to the settings at https://manage.stripe.com/#account/webhooks
// 4. Have fun!

// set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// see your keys here https://manage.stripe.com/account
//Stripe::setApiKey("YOUR STRIPE SECREY KEY");
Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_WggOmz2smwT9nGdx7aos2R5Q");


// retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);

// for extra security, retrieve from the Stripe API
$event_id = $event_json->id;
$event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);

// This will send receipts on succesful invoices
if $event->type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded' {
  email_invoice_receipt(event->data->object);
}

function email_invoice_receipt($invoice) {
  $customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($invoice->customer);

  //Make sure to customize your from address
  $subject = 'Your payment has been received';
  $headers = 'From: "MyApp Support" <support@myapp.com>';

  mail($customer->email, $subject, message_body(), $headers);
}

function format_stripe_amount($amount) {
  return sprintf('$%0.2f', $amount / 100.0);
}

function format_stripe_timestamp($timestamp) {
  return strftime("%m/%d/%Y", $timestamp);
}

function payment_received_body($invoice, $customer) {
  $subscription = $invoice->lines->subscriptions[0];
  return <<'EOF'
Dear {$customer->email}:

This is a receipt for your subscription. This is only a receipt,
no payment is due. Thanks for your continued support!

-------------------------------------------------
SUBSCRIPTION RECEIPT

Email: {$customer->email}
Plan: {$subscription->plan->name}
Amount: {format_stripe_amount($invoice->total)} (USD)

For service between {format_stripe_timestamp($subscription->period->start)} and {format_stripe_timestamp($subscription->period->end)}

-------------------------------------------------

EOF;
}

?>
```

Comment: That gist needs to be fixed https://gist.github.com/boucher/1708172 - So many syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the braces in your `if` statement:

```
if $event->type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded'
```

should be:

```
if ($event->type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded')
```

Comment: That changed the error too `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)`

Comment: on line 25, one line down.

Comment: `email_invoice_receipt(event->data->object);` missing a `$` - `email_invoice_receipt($event->data->object);` least, I think that's what it should be. Seems like it as per `$event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);` @TomSawyer

Comment: @TomSawyer You should take a look at the basic php syntax, you are missing a `$` for your variable name.

Comment: Sorry I should have caught those, I am getting one last error on line 48 `syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)`

Comment: @TomSawyer Yeah, I was just going over that now `return <<'EOF'` remove the quotes and there should be 3x of those `<`, as per the manual on heredoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc - `return <<<EOF`

Comment: @TomSawyer So, were are we at; solved? Problems? Working on it? Gone to get us all a cappuccino? ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- No milk in my coffee please.

Comment: @jeroen You got it ;-)

Comment: I think the OP's left us. What am I going to do with this extra coffee? Since they never came back, I decided to go there myself.

Comment: Hey, im not getting a error, but the original instructions was to use this as a webhook and have a email delivered, stripes webhooks say its a success but has no response and I receive no email.

Comment: Flight now leaving for Turino via gate 3... *arrivederci*